# Cannot resolve symbol @ReadOnly and @Mutable in Kotlin 1.1.0 compilation

Tags: java, kotlin

I got errors "Cannot resolve symbol ReadOnly" and "Cannot resolve symbole Mutable" in compiling with Kotlin 1.1.0. Is @ReadOnly and @Mutable not available with Kotlin 1.1.0? The following is a sample code.

SampleList.java Kotlin 1.0.7

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Mutable;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleList {
    @ReadOnly // Can resolve symbol 'ReadOnly'
    public static List<Integer> getReadOnlyList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Mutable // Can resolve symbol 'Mutable'
    public static List<Integer> getMutableList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

SampleList.java Kotlin 1.1.0

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Mutable;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleList {
    @ReadOnly // Cannot resolve symbol 'ReadOnly'
    public static List<Integer> getReadOnlyList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Mutable // Cannot resolve symbol 'Mutable'
    public static List<Integer> getMutableList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry. Adding **kotlin-compiler** enabled **@Mutable** and **@ReadOnly**. The settings of build.gradle are as follows.

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:$kotlin_version" // Added
    ...
}
```