# Proguard and Kotlin-Reflect/Kotlin Annotations

Tags: proguard, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Looking for some help from someone who puts the pro in proguard.

Annotations used by kotlin-reflect (required dependency for jackson-module-kotlin v v2.8.8) are getting stripped out after upgrading to kotlin 1.1.2-3. The error from proguard is:
 `Warning:kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.CallableDescriptor: can't find referenced class org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly`

This is happening for a few annotations, not just ReadOnly. We have tried adding a good ol' catch all but the error still exists:

```
-keep class org.jetbrains.kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class org.jetbrains.annotations.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly public *;
}
```

Looking at the source for `ReadOnly` it is an `@interface` with `java.lang.annotations.*` imported for `@Documented`, `@RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, `@Target`

Comment: Adding a note that we have tried adding the keepclassmembers and we do have keepAttributes

`-keepattributes *Annotation*`

`-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly public *;
}`

Comment: If this started happening after the Kotlin upgrade, I suggest you file a ticket [on their bug tracking system](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/kotlin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix for us was to add `dontwarn` for the reflect warnings.

```
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.CallableDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ClassDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ClassifierDescriptorWithTypeParameters
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.AnnotationDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.PropertyDescriptorImpl
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.JavaClassFinder
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.DescriptorSubstitutor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.DescriptorSubstitutor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeConstructor
```

These annotations exist in kotlin-compiler which is why proguard can't find them. Just ignore the warning instead of adding kotlin-compiler as a dependency (as this issue suggests [Cannot resolve symbol @ReadOnly and @Mutable in Kotlin 1.1.0 compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043767/cannot-resolve-symbol-readonly-and-mutable-in-kotlin-1-1-0-compilation)).

This may be a bug in kotlin-reflect; they should provide proguard rules to hide this from integrating apps.

Answer (score 10):

Or a shorter version:

`-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**`